# Web API authentication for Android app using both Facebook and Forms based authentication

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, facebook-android-sdk

My Android application uses Facebook Android SDK to create the FB Login button and also allow users to log in using their username and password.

So my question is, how can I authenticate and authorize these users on my ASP.Net Web API on each call?

Comment: I also want answer to this, but my requirement is Google+ API instead of Facebook SDK.